# Qual é a diferença de usar background para background-color?

Tags: css

Tenho esse código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <style>
      div {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        background: url("imagem/img1.jpg");
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

O código de cima tanto faz eu colocar `background` e `background-image` que funciona qual é a diferença?

Comment: `background` é uma propriedade mais abrangente, a outra é específica...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No caso a propriedade background-image só poderia ter apenas um unico valor.

```
background-image: url("imagem/img1.jpg");
```

E se no caso se você quisesse colocar `background-repeat: no-repeat` para a imagem não repetir? fácil adicione a propriedade.

```
background-image: url("imagem/img1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

E para a imagem ficar fixa e alterar a posição? obviamente adicione as propriedades.

```
background-image: url("imagem/img1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

E se caso a minha imagem tiver o fundo transparente e eu quisesse adicionar uma cor de fundo? é a última vez! adicione a propriedade.

```
background-color: rgb(140, 50, 190);
background-image: url("imagem/img1.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

Você, notou alguma coisa no último trecho de código? aqui caso se você quisesse alterar a cor, imagem, não repetir, fixar e a posição você teria que definir 5 propriedades e isso deixa seu código `CSS` muito grande e para isso tem a propriedade `background`, que é uma propriedade de taquigrafia ou seja uma propriedade abreviada com ela você define as 5 propriedades as que eu citei no código em cima em apenas uma unica propriedade.

```
background: rgb(140, 50, 190) url("imagem/img1.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 50%;
```

Parece meio complicado mais não, é só seguir essa ordem independentemente se um dos valores estiver faltando.

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

Ao longo você vai se aprofundando mais no `CSS` você vai vendo que existe outras propriedades de taquigrafia(abreviada) e aposto que você já fez o uso de algumas.

```
margin
padding
border
border-radius
animation
transition
```

Answer (score 7):

`background-color` é uma propriedade específica para definir a cor de fundo de um elemento. [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) é um [*"atalho"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties) que permite combinar várias propriedades relacionadas ao background de uma única vez. Exemplo:

```
/* isto: */
background: #333 

/* seria o mesmo que: */
background-color: #333
```

```
/* isto: */
background: url('foo.png') no-repeat 

/* seria o mesmo que: */
background-image: url('foo.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat
```

Existem várias outras propriedades [*"shorthands"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties), um exemplo de uso muito comum é o `border`. Ao invés de especificar:

```
border-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red
```

Você pode simplificar em:

```
border: 1px solid red
```

Answer (score 6):

Tem coisa que não são propriamente diferentes, mas que podem te trazer dor de cabeça se vc não entender o que está acontecendo... Vou te mostrar uns exemplos

O que vc acha que vai acontecer com o css abaixo? Vc acha que o background vai ficar vermelho ou não?

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
    background: no-repeat;
}
```

Isso mesmo... **não vai ficar vermelho**, pois o `background` vai sobrescrever o `background-color` e o seu `body` vai ficar sem cor!

E agora seu eu inverter a ordem o que acontece?

```css
body {
    background: no-repeat;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Agora sim... dessa vez o `background` vai ficar vermelho :)

---

**Exemplo 2**

E agora o `BG` vai ficar `red` ou com a `imagem`?

```css
body {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/10/10);
}
```

Agora é fácil, vai ficar com a imagem é claro :)

Mas e se a gente inverter??

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/10/10);
    background-color: red;
}
```

Vai ficar `red` pq o `background-color` vem depois do `background-image`... **ERRADO**! Vai continuar com a imagem, pq o bg-imagem tem prioridade na renderização independente da posição. A imagem é um conteúdo externo que vai ficar por cima da cor. Bem vindo ao mundo do CSS...

---

Outros pontos

Com `bg-color` vc só pode ter uma cor de fundo, mas com `linear` ou `radial` gradiente vc pode ter várias cores de fundo inclusive uma por cima da outra...

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    background: 
        
        linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, #000e 50%), 
        linear-gradient(to right, #f00c 50%, #00fc 100%),
        url(https://unsplash.it/100/100);
}
```

Comment: Mas então uso a background-image?

Comment: @DomDomdomdom não necessariamente.  Se vc quer uma cor sólida de fundo coloque background: red; se vc quer uma imagem ou uma mistura de cor tipo um gradiente use o background-image. Como vc ainda está aprendendo, evite usar o shorthand "background", de preferencia nesse momento por escrever cada uma das propriedades do background, isso vai te ajudar a entender o que é o que e como cada propriedade funciona. Esse texto está em português e já vai te dar uma boa luz https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/background abs

Comment: Tá bom então, brigadão por responder!